# Angular suddenly requires rewrite of img source to relative path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cloud9-ide

For the last three weeks I had my Angular website working with `ui-router` and states.

Thus a state looks as follows:

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: '/templates/home.html',
    controller:'HomeCtrl as home',
  })
```

In the file `home.html`, the way I added an image was by simply pointing to the `img` folder as follows:

```
<img src="img/boo.png">
```

This worked all the time fine.

Now however, when I tried to run the page in my Cloud9, it said that it cannot find boo.png. However when I write:

```
<img src="../img/boo.png">
```

Then it works fine.

What could have happened that this sudden rewrite is needed?

Comment: the folder structure changed?

Comment: nothing, it is exactly the same

Comment: Did this work differently before on Cloud9? or you just moved the code to Cloud9 and it was different? Also, which server are you using? Apache?

Comment: Worked fine in Cloud9 before. It is since the .c9.io changed to c9users.io

Comment: Can you paste a picture of your workspace file tree? showing the img folder? Also, can you tell me which server you're using?

Comment: Solved it by writing ng-src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by rewriting all

```
<img src="..">
```

to:

```
<img ng-src="..">
```

Don't know what happened, but it works fine now.